# Bootstrap-datepicker inline get Date on click in short format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am a beginner and trying the [Bootstrap-Datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/). I am using it embedded/inline like in [this Demo](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=embedded&format=dd%2Fmm%2Fyyyy&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=linked&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&daysOfWeekDisabled=0&daysOfWeekDisabled=6&daysOfWeekHighlighted=4&daysOfWeekHighlighted=5&todayHighlight=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox).

It works, but I want that the selected Date to be displayed in a label/textbox etc. when clicked on a Date. So far I only got the Date after I click on a Button, but more worse it is a huge line like 
`Thu Mar 30.2017 00:00:00 GMT +100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)`.
I want it simple like `30.03.2017` or `30. Mar.2017`.

What should I do?

PS. The first 2 solutions work but gives the long line back. The other 2 give `undefined` back.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pickyDate"> </div>
    <div>
      <input  type="text" placeholder="Date shown here"  id="showDate"/
    </div>
    <!-- Testing here -->
    <div> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="showTestDate()">Danger Button</button>
      <span class="label label-danger" id="DateTest">Danger Label</span>
      <span class="label label-info" id="lbl2">Info Label</span>
      <span class="label label-info" id="lbl3">Info Label</span>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#pickyDate').datepicker({
          format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
          todayBtn: "linked",
          language: "de",
          daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
          daysOfWeekHighlighted: "4",
          todayHighlight: true,
        }); 
      })
      /* Need it in Format dd mm yyyy */
      function showTestDate(){
        /** works but output is too long */
        var datelist = $('#pickyDate').datepicker('getDate');
        document.getElementById("DateTest").innerText = datelist;   

        var valueDate = $("#pickyDate").datepicker("getDate");
        document.getElementById("showDate").value = valueDate;

        /** works not 'undefined' */
        var ndate = $("#pickyDate").data("datepicker").date;
        document.getElementById("lbl2").innerText = ndate;

        var myDate=window.document.getElementById("pickyDate").value;
        document.getElementById("lbl3").innerText=myDate;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `datepicker('getFormattedDate')` instead of [`datepicker('getDate')`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/methods.html#getdate). `getDate` retuns a JavaScript Date object that will show in the long format mentionend in the question.

Change [`format`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#format) option to `dd.mm.yyyy` to get date with numeric month or to `dd-M-yyyy` to get abbreviated month name.

When you selcet a date the [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html#changedate) event is fired, so you can attach a listner to it to update your input, labels etc.

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#pickyDate').datepicker({
  format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
  todayBtn: "linked",
  language: "de",
  daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
  daysOfWeekHighlighted: "4",
  todayHighlight: true,
}).on('changeDate', showTestDate);

function showTestDate(){
  var value = $('#pickyDate').datepicker('getFormattedDate');
  $("#showDate").val(value);
  $("#DateTest").html(value);
  $("#lbl2").html(value);
  $("#lbl3").html(value);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js"></script>

<div id="pickyDate"></div>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Date shown here"  id="showDate"/>
</div>
<!-- Testing here -->
<div> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="showTestDate()">Get date</button>
  <span class="label label-danger" id="DateTest">Danger Label</span>
  <span class="label label-info" id="lbl2">Info Label</span>
  <span class="label label-info" id="lbl3">Info Label</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the

> `format: "dd/mm/yyyy",`

in your script to

> `format: "dd-M-yyyy"`

Here's the working jsFiddle [Date Picker Format](http://jsfiddle.net/vjbhaskar93/8w8v9/2910/)

Hope it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: The Result is still `Tue Mar 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)`

Comment: try with dd-M-yyyy.
Please refer this documentation for full understanding of date notations
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate